# How to make Maps drop a pin - iOS 5

Tags: ios, google-maps

The following code opens the Maps app in the right position and with the right zoom, but how can I make Maps drop a pin at that exact position?

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:
                                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=%f,%f&z=%d",
                                              self.latitude,
                                              self.longitude,
                                              17]] ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query based link:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=asdsad@%f,%f&z=%d

Example:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=aplace@12,13&z=5

Comment: thanks that worked! And I'd like to remember to future reader of this post to use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding if the name of the place has spaces ;)